# How can I add multiple lists in ObservableList in javafx iterating through it?

Tags: java, javafx

1. Can I Do something like this ?

   ```
   ObservableList<FoodItems> data=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   data =FXCollections.observableArrayList(
   for(int i=0;i<fruits.size();i++) {
   new FoodItems(fruits.add(i), flowers.add(i), bakeryitems.add(i));
   }
   ```

   where `FoodItems` is the class with getter and setter methods and here data must be added to ObservableList : data

Comment: your code seems to be incomplete!!

Comment: ObservableList<FoodItems> data=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
data =FXCollections.observableArrayList(
for(int i=0;i<fruits.size();i++) {
new FoodItems(fruits.add(i), flowers.add(i), bakeryitems.add(i));
}

Comment: Can anyone help me in answering this  ??

Comment: I tried it  ObservableList<FoodItems> data =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   for(int i=0;i<fruits.size();i++) {
   TestcasesDetails element=new FoodItems(fruits.get(i), flowers.get(i),bakeryitems.get(i));
   data.add(i, element);
   }

Comment: in method argument you are writing loop.. i don't think that is valid!!1

Comment: for above logic am not writing in method argument......It worked !!!!! and Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it should be:

```
    ObservableList<FoodItems> data = FXCollections.<FoodItems>observableArrayList();

    for( int i=0; i<fruits.size(); i++ ) 
    {
        data.add( new FoodItems( fruits.add(i), flowers.add(i), bakeryitems.add(i) ) );
    }
```